# Save and retrive data from a custom form to database

Tags: forms

I want to build a webapp using wordpress to manage the fornt-end templating and data input. the app will display a wizard, a map to locate the user and a for to insert some information about the location. I will also add a search form that will look from the data inserted by users and will display the results if found. My question is, how I can save some data to the wordpress database, is there any specific function to let wordpress manage the form inputs? I need to create a separate database table or I can rely on the existing wordpress database tables structure? Can anyone point me into the right direction? I don't have any code sample at the moment, this because I want to understand first how to proceed with the custom form that will be showed to the user to collect the data. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally depends on your sow. You can choose custom table to insert custom data and that's need so much code like mysql query to insert data and fetching data using the same approach. If you feel comfortable with those approach you can look for wordpress WPDB.

But to me if you want to build a system which store data from the custom form and stores on the table and display on the wordpress admin panel as well then you might need to go with wordpress default conventional tables. By using custom post type. In this way you can easily display the stored data in the admin dashboard as well as admin can easily change , delete it. And that's a default features.

Comment: Custom post type will not be useful in this case, I need to store personal information of an user so a traditional table will be better than a post that is accessible by anyone

Comment: Then you can check wpdb for interacting with mysql

Comment: I will read the documentation about it. For the data submit to the backend, is there any particular function I need to follow? I know that to submit data wordpress need some hidden fields

Comment: I didn't get your question properly. Could you explain so that I can guide you in a proper way.

Comment: Usually wordpress forms require an hidden field to set an action that needs to be associated with a function called by `add_action()`. I don't remember well the hook to call, but without it if I remember well, wordpress will not manage the data. `admin_action` or similar

Comment: There is a lot of things that you need to do for achieving your goal. But it is possible and here is not possible to tell you that much things.